# How to reference a directory in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

This is probably a pretty simple question. But in my Laravel project I have my User.php file which is located in

> App\Models\User.php

And I need to call it in a file that is located in App\Http\Controllers.

So I reference it as

> App\Models\User

but instead the code thinks I'm saying

> App\Http\Controllers\App\Models\User

Which obviously is incorrect and causes and error. How do I reference a directory in Laravel that's outside the one I'm currently in?

Comment: because of namespacing ... if you are in a declared namespace then the references will be based off of the current namespace ... you should import/alias the class with a `use` statement

Comment: Using which code? By "_reference a directory_" you mean how to correctly use namespaces?

Comment: Ah yeah, namespaces. Apologies if I'm using any incorrect wording as I'm pretty new. How can I use that kind of statement to use a namespace outside of the one I'm in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to learn about how namespace works.

I suppose at the top of your controller file, there is a line

`namespace App\Http\Controllers;`

so If in your code you wrote

`$c = new A\B\C()`

it looks for `App\Http\Controllers\A\B\C`. You have two options:

1. use `$c = new \A\B\C`, in your case, `\App\Models\User`
2. add the namespace alias on the top under the namespace line:
   `use App\Models\User;`
   And then in your code `$user = new User`

Comment: Thank you! I'll definitely learn more about how namespaces work as it looks like I was missing out on that, but in the meantime this fixed my problem.